# Cant load ionicons's fonts

Tags: webpack, sass, laravel-mix, ionicons

My folder structure:

```
/dist
    index.html
    /css
        app.css
    /js
        app.js  
    /fonts
        /vendor
            /ionicons
                /dist
                    ionicons.eot
                    ionicons.svg
                    ionicons.ttf
                    ionicons.woff
                    ionicons.woff2
    /node_modules..             
    /src
        /assets
                /js
                    app.js
                /sass
                    app.scss
```

Webpack:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.setPublicPath('dist');

mix.js('src/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')
   .sass('src/assets/sass/app.scss', 'dist/css');
```

app.scss:

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

//ionicons
$ionicons-font-path: "~ionicons/dist/fonts";
@import '~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons';
```

Now, I have an **HTML** file inside **dist** folder "index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="example">
     Hello!
    <i class="icon ion-md-heart text-white"></i>
 </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I open it using chrome: **file:///D:/Projects/exampleproject/dist/index.html**

The page does loads bootstrap 4 , and ionicons's **only css without the fonts**!
It shows me this:

```
ionicons.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ionicons.woff:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ionicons.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: You can't simply run the .html file in your browser, you need a server to serve those assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the reference to the font files. The related files called in a `css` (like `@import`, `background-image`, and other kind of file references such as source for web fonts) are relative to the folder from where the `css` file is loaded.

So in your case, in order for the font files to be loaded properly, they will need to be referenced relative to `/dist/css` so you should change the source path for your fonts files to `../fonts/vendor/ionicons/dist/`:

```
$ionicons-font-path: '../fonts/vendor/ionicons/dist/fonts";
@import '~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons';
```

Or if you run your project in a web server, you could simply reference the files from your document root. In that case you could use `/fonts/vendor/ionicons/dist/`.